# non-convex Polytope definition

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

I have a simple question. I read that given a vector space $N_{\mathbb{R}}$ over $\mathbb{R}$,
we can define a convex polytope in the following way:

$$P:= \Big\{ \sum_{u\in S} \mu_u u \,\Big| \, \mu_u \geq 0 , \sum_{u\in S} \mu_u =1 \Big\} \subset N_{\mathbb{R}}$$

with $S$ finite.

What is the definition of polytope and regular polytope in general?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently wikipedia has a very broad definition of polytope

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope

But I have only seen polytope be used to mean that definition, which immediately implies that it is convex

Comment: There are various definitions of what *regularity* should mean in Coxeter's book *Regular polytopes*.

Comment: The title of your question ("non-convex") does not match the question itself.  Perhaps you are seeking a definition of a *polytopal complex*?  This is defined in Ziegler's *Lectures on Polytopes*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This should be a comment, but don´t know how to post it as such)

The words "polytope" and "polyhedron" can mean different things... and different people mean different things when they say "regular polytope".

Take a look at Grünbaum´s paper: 
Are your polyhedra the same as my polyhedra?, Discrete and Computational Geometry: The Goodman-Pollack Festschrift.  B. Aronov,  S. Basu,  J. Pach,  and  Sharir, M., eds.  Springer,  New York 2003, pp. 461 – 488 (http://www.math.washington.edu/~grunbaum/Your%20polyhedra-my%20polyhedra.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

One possible definition is that a concrete polytope is an abstract polytope where each vertex has been assigned to a point in space, and all elements of rank n are contained in nD subspaces.

Comment: This is nearly my preferred definition. I would say that an (abstract) element of rank $n$ is assigned to (rather than contained in) an $n$-dimensional subspace. There's no reference to a particular subset of this subspace; this eliminates problems with "holes" like the centre of a star polytope. -- You could also provide a definition or link for abstract polytopes.

Answer (score 0):

The *pentagram* either can be considered as a sequence of 5 sides circling around the center twice, or as a stellation of the central pentagon. The same applies to the halfspace generations of polytopes of any dimension too. Just cf. to

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_(polytope)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellation

--- rk